# Home Button Service Background Music

Tags: android, audio, android-service, android-homebutton

I have a background music which is in Service, it works fine but when I pressed the HOME Button the music won't stop. Help me.

Service:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.haha);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}
public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}
public void onPause() {

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
```

This is my Activity where have the intent:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


   Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);//This is the intent
    startService(svc);  

    View adventuretime1 = this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    adventuretime1.setOnClickListener(this);

    View advanced2 = this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    advanced2.setOnClickListener(this);


}

            @Override
            public void onBackPressed(){

              new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
              .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                          startActivity(intent);
                                          System.exit(0);
                                       }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
            }           


public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent button1 = new Intent(this, AdventureTime.class);
        startActivity(button1);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        Intent button2 = new Intent(this, AdvancedKids.class);
        startActivity(button2);
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a Service and Services are supposed to have a longer life time that your UI activity or fragments. From your code I don't see the case where you are handling the HOME button click in your app and stopping the service or likewise. You should probably be doing that.Its just another H/W button which triggers events on which you can piggyback.

By the way whats `System.exit(0);` doing in your android code?

Comment: For the sound to stop when I click yes to the AlertDialog

Comment: kill / unbind or stop your service there. What has HOME button got to do with this? that alert is being shown on back  button press.  Back and Home are different buttons and remember Service doesn't die with your activity.

Comment: I tried to replaced it with  Intent svc= new Intent();
                                           stopService(svc);  But It didn't stop.

Comment: use what Chen has posted below. A broadcast when the Home button is clicked.

Comment: I don't know where to put that. I'm newbie sorry. :(

Comment: why don't you try the service class :)

Comment: I tried it there but the "context" in the context.registerReceiver have an error. :o

Answer (score 0):

Because when you click the **HOME_BUTTON**,the service **will not** call **onDestory()**.

You can register a broadcastReceiver for the **HOME_BUTTON**,like this:

```
context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //destory the service if you want
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

Comment: Where I will put that?

Comment: Sorry Im newbie. Can you tell me, i tried in service class but i have error with the "context" on the first line of code you send.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to stop the Service, then you can call [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) method.

Comment: I tried it but, it stop whenever I go to another activity. I need the bgmusic continously. Please help me.